# Storm: Kafka to HDFS - dependency jar issues

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-kafka, apache-storm, kafka-consumer-api

I have built a storm topology, that consumes data from kafka and writes into hdfs.

When using storm & kafka dependencies like below,

```
<storm.version>0.10.0.2.3.4.0-3485</storm.version>
<kafka.version>0.8.2.1</kafka.version>
```

topology is failing with below stated exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: kafka.javaapi.consumer.SimpleConsumer.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;IIILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V 
at storm.kafka.DynamicPartitionConnections.register(DynamicPartitionConnections.java:60) 
at storm.kafka.PartitionManager.<init>(PartitionManager.java:66) 
at storm.kafka.ZkCoordinator.refresh(ZkCoordinator.java:98) 
at storm.kafka.ZkCoordinator.getMyManagedPartitions(ZkCoordinator.java:69) at storm.kafka.KafkaSpout.nextTuple(KafkaSpout.java:138) 
at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__7098$fn__7113$fn__7142.invoke(executor.clj:596) 
at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__543.invoke(util.clj:475) 
at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

But, When using storm & kafka dependencies like below,

```
<storm.version>0.9.3.2.2.4.0-2633</storm.version>
<kafka.version>0.8.2.1</kafka.version>
```

topology is running fine and downloading messages and writing to hdfs , without any issues!!

Can someone please help what is the causing the issue and help me fix the issue !

Comment: Are you using HDP cluster?

Comment: @RakeshRakshit yeah, on HDP

Comment: Please look if your HDP stack supports Kafka 0.8

Comment: @RakeshRakshit Thanks for your response. Can you please give some more details on how to check that ?

Comment: Are you using HDP 2.3.4 or  HDP 2.4.2? What is the HDP version?

Comment: @RakeshRakshit Its HDP 2.3.4.0-3485

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123583/discussion-between-rakesh-rakshit-and-raja).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **HDP 2.3.4** supports **Kafka-0.9** out of the box.

And it is not recommended to use a version different from the HDP stack since the behavior has not been tested and hence unsupported.

References:
https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.4/bk_HDP_RelNotes/content/ch_relnotes_v234.html

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the storm-kafka dependency from this:

```
<groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
<artifactId>storm-kafka</artifactId>
<version>${storm.version}</version>
<scope>compile</scope>
```

to this:

```
<groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
<artifactId>storm-kafka</artifactId>
<version>0.9.3.2.2.4.0-2633</version>
<scope>compile</scope>
```

And keeping the Storm and Kafka version to this:

```
<storm.version>0.10.0.2.3.4.0-3485</storm.version>
<kafka.version>0.8.2.1</kafka.version>
```